# Query JSON fields with OData and Entity Framework

Tags: json, odata, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core app with SQL Server 2016, which is accessed using EF Core.

One of the fields in the table we're working on contains JSON data (as NVARCHAR), which is accessed using SQL Server's JSON functions.
The JSON looks similar to this:

```
 {"log" : {
     "date" : "2018-01-02 12:04:33",
     "IP" : "233.24.122.97",
     "Severity" : "INFO"
     }
 }
```

We would like to implement OData on top of our controllers, which will enable us to query the tables dynamically. To make the functionality complete, we would like to query the OData fields.

Now, we know EF Core does not support JSON querying as of now, but we can work around it and manipulate the LINQ query manually.

Our problem lies with the OData query.

We would like to be able to use query like this:

```
 http://server/api/logs?$filter=log/Severity eq 'INFO'
```

Our problem is that this query causes an exception at the OData / ASP.NET level, states that:

```
  ODataException: could not find a property named log/Severity On type LogRecord
```

(LogRecord is the entity type containing the JSON Data in addition to other, regular, fields).

How can we construct an OData query that uses fields which are not directly related to the entity but to a JSON field inside it?

Comment: Does /logs?$filter=contains(log,'INFO') work? I may have messed up the query a tad but basically if you treat the it as a nvarchar can you query it?

Comment: I'm not sure that will do. How can I make a gt or lt queries using this technique?

Comment: Did you get this working? I am also questioning myself to design something similar...

Comment: Nope... We ended with a complicated and semi-manual process that stores the JSON-related parms in the context, and then adding the appropriate SQL JSON functions to the generated SQL. Not fun.